# How to get Get parameter from url in grails

Tags: grails

I have a project where I am creating links like this:

http://abcdefc.com/Nfploginsystem/registration/resetpass?key=1234

The action for that link gets set like `<g:form action="chkresetpass" method="GET">`
I want to pass the name of the controller as a key="value" pair like:  `action="chkresetpass"`
So, the controller can respond with code like this:

```
def chkresetpass(){  
       flash.message= params.key 
       redirect(action:"resetpass");
       }
```

but i'm not able to get that parameter from the url -! 
Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: params.key not working?

Comment: params.key should be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the:

```
http://abcdefc.com/Nfploginsystem/registration/resetpass?key=1234
```

to:

```
http://abcdefc.com/Nfploginsystem/registration/chkresetpass?key=1234
```

and now on the chkresetpass action you will have params.key

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows you how to use params

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html

So `params.key`